# Trying to install EntityFramework in PCL

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, portable-class-library

I'm currently trying to build a project that requires a repository pattern to be implemented. However, I the main project library is a portable class library so as far as I can tell all my other libraries must be Portable class libraries too. I'm currently trying to add a install EntityFramework from Nuget but I'm getting this error indicated below.

> Package EntityFramework 6.1.3 is not compatible with dotnet5.0 (.NETPlatform,Version=v5.0). Package EntityFramework 6.1.3 supports:
>     - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
>     - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)

I have tried a number of work arounds like using .NetStandard, referencing ASP.NET core etc but none of these have worked.

Can anyone tell me is there anyway for me to use a regular class library and still have it work in the project? Or is there a way for me to install EntityFramework?

Thanks

Comment: did you try to downgrade the target framework to you project properties ?

Comment: Thanks a million! I had downgraded the properties to .net 4.5.1 but was using ASP.Net Core.  I think this was causing the problem.

Comment: i have added as answer to your question , please upvote or mark as solution if it was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to downgrade the targeted framework from you project properties to `.NET 4.0` or `4.5`

Comment: So I was able to add a reference to entity framework but can't seem to use any of the features such as EntityTypeConfiguration<>. It seems that I still can't reference System.Data.Entity. Do you know what the problem is here if so is it fixable? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: The only thing I could think to do was restart visual studio, I'm really not sure what to do here. Can't find much help online

Comment: i will search for any solution for this , or can you please describe the problem clearly ...

Comment: Basically I'm creating a simulation using Xenko game engine. This supports .net version 4.6, I need to add a repository pattern for data acces, therefore I need entity framework. In my db context class the I am inheriting from the EntityFramework DbContext. EntityFramework has this class in a library called System.Data.Entity. For some reason even though I have entity framework installed this reference is still not working

Comment: i see. but EntityFramework 6.1.3 is not compatibile with .NET 4.6. so you need for your project .NET 4.6 but it cannot be used with entity 6.3.1

Comment: Yeah I found the problem, PCL's are not compatable with System.Data. :( Looks like I'm back to the drawing board